# DHCP on windows 2003 problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dhcp, internal-dns

i have setup DHCP server in my home on windows 2003 server domain controller.

my IP range in DHCP server is: 192.168.1.20 - 192.168.1.25

and also configure to give DNS to 192.168.1.14

but after i login from my notebook with Dynamic IP & Dynamic DNS i got following IP

192.168.1.3
and DNS empty

i am also using router with ip: 192.168.1.1 and also setup router ip in DHCP configration

any solution?

Thanks

Comment: exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/120029/windows-2003-server-dhcp-and-dns-configration

Answer (score 2):

Does your router also give out DHCP addresses? If so you'll want to turn that off.

When you look at the connection properties, does it list your server as the DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

You have another DHCP server on the network handing out IP's.  You must disable this! refer to your router manual on how to do this.

Run an `ipconfig /all` on a client.  Look for the line:

> DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 191.168.1.x

If the IP in there is different to your windows DHCP server, then hunt it down & eliminate it.

Comment: my router DHCP is off, and now when i see ipconfig my DHCP server is : 192.168.1.1 my router ip ?

Comment: Does the router need a reboot for that config change to take effect? Might be worth it, just because.