# windows 2003 server DHCP and DNS configration

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dhcp

i have my notebook in Windows 2003 server domain where server IP is: 192.168.1.14

to access all the features off domain like folder redirection / printer sharing

i need to change my laptop DNS to 192.168.1.14 as shown in picture

[image]

this DNS in TCP/IP is big trouble, cause when i am not in my office and need to access internet i need to chnage it again to Obtain DNS server address Automatically.

is there any way that i choose "Obtain DNS server address Automatically" on my system and when i am in office my DNS automatically set to "192.168.1.14" from server.

i search on internet about that and found that if i have installed DHCP and DNS service on my Domain server.

i installed both, DHCP and DNS but not working...

my DHCP server configuration is bellow

[image]

and my DNS server configuration is bellow

[image]
i can't figure out where is error?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you authorized the DHCP server?

Open the DHCP MMC.

In the console tree, click DHCP.

On the Action menu, click Manage authorized servers.

The Manage Authorized Servers dialog box appears.

Click Authorize.

When prompted, type the name or IP address of the DHCP server to be authorized, and then click OK.